# Stream and filter a SortedMap

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11, sortedmap

I am sure this is straightforward but for some reason I am not getting what I want.

I have a `SortedMap<String, String>` values and I want to stream and filter through it and save only some values.

For example:

```
    SortedMap<String, String> input = new TreeMap<>();
    values.put("accepted.animal", "dog");
    values.put("accepted.bird", "owl");
    values.put("accepted.food", "broccoli");
    values.put("rejected.animal", "cat");
    values.put("rejected.bird", "eagle");
    values.put("rejected.food", "meat");
```

I only want to keep values that contain "accepted" in the key and drop everything else.

So, the result would be:

```
{accepted.animal=dog, accepted.bird=owl, accepted.food=broccoli}
```

How do I stream through the map and filter out everything except keys that contain "accepted"?

This is what I tried:

```
private SortedMap<String, String> process(final Input input) {
    final SortedMap<String, String> results = new TreeMap<>();

    return input.getInputParams()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(params -> params.getKey().contains("accepted"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

But it fails due to "Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another variant of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) such that you pass the merge function and supplier to collect as a `TreeMap` there :

```
return input.getInputParams()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(params -> params.getKey().startsWith("accepted")) // small change
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> b, TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: Thanks much! This is exactly what I was looking for. One thing I forgot to ask in my original question was - once `params.getKey().startsWith(..)` is true then I wanted to replace "accepted" with "found". Is it possible to do before .collect()?

Comment: @AMagic you can `map` the entries, but it is preferred to avoid mutating objects while using streams.

Comment: I tried to `map` the entries, but I don't see any option to `setKey`. I am ttrying to change the key, not value. `accepted.brid:owl` to `found.bird:owl` Is it possible to add a snippet to your answer above, please?

Comment: @AMagic It should look something like `.filter(params -> params.getKey().startsWith("accepted")).map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey().replace("accepted","found"), entry.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b, TreeMap::new))`.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the method doesn't compile because `Collectors.toMap()` returns `Map`, whereas the method signature requires a return type of `SortedMap`.

I don't know the reason behind the misleading "static context" error message; but when I attempt to build the code with Gradle I get a *slightly* more helpful message.

> `error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
>                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
>                           ^
>       equality constraints: Map<K,U>
>       lower bounds: SortedMap<String,String>,Object`

You probably want the overloaded version of `Collectors.toMap()` that accepts a `Supplier<Map>`, so that you can provide a `SortedMap` for output.

Comment: Thank you jaco0646. I don't know why I was getting the misleading error message. But I understood what you are saying. I did overload `Collectors.toMap()` as suggested by Naman. I've asked one missed question though. Once `params.getKey().startsWith(..)` is true then I wanted to `replace "accepted" with "found"`. Is it possible to do before .collect()?